# How to cast to a dynamic class?

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I am trying use [filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)class builder but I am kinda confused on what to do with it.

```
       var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("temp", ",") { IgnoreFirstLines = 0, IgnoreEmptyLines = true, Delimiter = ","  };
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var headerArray = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        foreach (var header in headerArray)
        {
            var fieldName = header.Replace("\"", "").Replace(" ", "");
            cb.AddField(fieldName, typeof(string));
        }

        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());
        var result = engine.ReadStream(sr);
```

The [DelimitedClassBuilder](http://www.filehelpers.com/FileHelpers.RunTime.DelimitedClassBuilder.html) takes in as it's first parameter a "className' and then "delimiter"

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Creates a new DelimitedClassBuilder.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   className:
    //     The valid class name.
    //
    //   delimiter:
    //     The delimiter for that class.
    public DelimitedClassBuilder(string className, string delimiter);
```

I then go through the first row of the stream what contains the header what I will later on use as the fieldNames for this "class".

The last line reads all the rest of the information and returns it as an object array[]. I see inside it they are of class "temp".

Yet I don't know how actually cast it to the class "temp". Right now I don't really know how to get at the data. I know I can't just do something like

result[0].SomeFieldName as the fieldName could change from run to run. So this also makes me wonder why it makes a class in the first place if I going to have to do something like get it by index or something.

As you can see right now I am very confused.

Comment: Casting means you have compile-time knowledge that the compiler can't infer. If you need to cast to something unknown, you should change your design to use an interface or inheritance to unify the common logic.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: 4.0 (so I can use dynamic if needed). I am just confused by the whole fact that it makes a class yet I don't understand what to do this runtime generated class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is demonstrated [in the examples](http://www.filehelpers.com/runtime_classes.html).

You use

```
DataTable dt = engine.ReadStreamAsDT(sr);
```

and then access the results with something like:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- Row ---"); // Print separator.
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) // Loop over the columns.
    {
        Console.Write("Item: "); // Print label.
        Console.WriteLine(item); 
        /// the Type of item will be whatever you defined when you
        /// called ClassBuilder.AddField() (String in your example)
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```